# Where to find more information on 'Software Project Simulation Board Games'?

Tags: project-management

On [Steve McConnell's blog](http://blogs.construx.com/blogs/stevemcc/archive/2009/01/07/2009-ecse-meeting-topics-announced.aspx) I saw a passing reference to: 'Software Project Simulation Board Games'.

I haven't heard of this before, and I was wondering where can I find more references on the topic.

Google wasn't of much help to begin with.

Comment: So, I turned to Google to see the results you got. I searched for "Software Project Simulation Board Games" without the quotes...the first hit was THIS QUESTION.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I went ahead and asked Steve:

> Alejandro,
>
> Our simulation games are games we've
>   developed for internal use. We don't
>   have any public description of them.
>   At some point we plan to offer a class
>   in which we mainly play simulation
>   games, but that's still in development
>   at this point.
>
> Cheers, Steve McConnell

So I guess the final answer is we will need to wait and see what they put on the public domain. Or go to one of ConstruX (McConnell's Company) seminars.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you ask Steve McConnell directly. In one of his articles he links his [facebook profile](http://www.facebook.com/pages/Steve-McConnell/198720075270) for example. Also there is an article about this topic by Gil Taran, which can be purchased [here](http://www2.computer.org/portal/web/csdl/doi/10.1109/CSEET.2007.54). Hope this helps.

Comment: yes Jiri. Asking McConnell himself was my next step.
I'll post whatever he says.